# how to refresh tinymce image_list dropdown

Tags: tinymce-6

How to refresh the image_list?  I have in the tinymce init:

image_list: masterImageList that references an existing external image store.

When the file picker is opened, the masterImageList loads and contains the existing Images.

After uploading an image, I'd like to refresh the list (masterImageList) so that the newly uploaded image appears there.  the users may choose to upload multiple images before consuming them in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Options configured in `tinymce.init` (including `image_list`) cannot be changed after the editor is initialized. To change these options, you would have to destroy and reinitialize the editor.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#destroy